# Using Zend_Navigation, how do I create image-based navigation?

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework, navigation

(I'm assuming my navigation should be in a layout script.)

I have a navigation bar composed of rollover images. The image corresponding to the page that is active should be a different color, though. I do this by changing the image. My question is, where and how should I implement this using Zend_Navigation?

**Details:** The menu itself is just a stack of divs that are floated to the left within a container. Each div has a background image.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Do you actually need to use Zend_Navigation? Benefits are built in ACL handling and the ability to render the same menu in different ways (menu, breadcrumbs, etc). If you don't need these features, I'd just create the menu manually in your layout or a view partial

Comment: Another question, could you potentially use CSS to provide the visual effects?

Comment: I'm not sure if I need Zend_Navigation, and it sounds like I don't. I am working on getting it to use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->navigation ()->breadcrumbs ()->setPartial ('your_own_breadcrumbs.phtml');
```

And then in `scripts/your_own_breadcrumbs.phtml` render the menu any way you like.

```
foreach ($this->pages as $page)
{
    ...
}
```